# Django Rest Framework with android error while sending email (Very unique)

Tags: python, django

I have created a Custom User model in Django rest framework for the Android application. I used `post-receive signals for Activate User model`. Everything works fine if I create the user without sending an email.

But when I send an email it shows user already exists and pings the registered URL twice creating the user second time. This error occurs only while using an android app but does not show when using postman. Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a password')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            **extra_fields
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            password=password,
            **extra_fields,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            useremail=username+"@antef.co.in",
            password=password,
            **extra_fields,
        )
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractUser):

    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'),
                                  max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'),
                                 max_length=150)
    username = models.CharField(_('Username'),
                                max_length=100, unique=True)
    useremail = models.EmailField(_('Useremail'),
                                  max_length=255, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(_('User Image'),
                              upload_to=settings.USERIMG_FOLDER, blank=True, default=settings.DEFAULT_FOLDER+'default_user.png')
    email = models.EmailField(_('Current Email Address'),
                              max_length=255, unique=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(_('Country Code'),
                                    blank=True, null=True, max_length=4)
    phone_number = models.CharField(_('Phone Number'),
                                    blank=True, null=True, max_length=15)
    social_acc = models.CharField(_('Social Account'),
                                    blank=True, null=True, max_length=5)
    # password = models.CharField(_('Password'), max_length=150)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.username)

class ActivateUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key = code_generator()
        super(ActivateUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def post_save_user_model_receiver(sender, instance, created,*args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            ActivateUser.objects.create(user=instance)
        except:
            pass
```

**views.py**

if i uncomment the send_mail function. it hits the server twice as shown in terminal image with selection

```
class UserCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    # def get(self, request):
    #     #do something with 'GET' method
    #     return HttpResponse("<h>Page not Found</h>")

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        if UserModel.objects.filter(username=data.get("username")).exists():
            return Response({'code': 'reg_fail', 'message': 'Username already exists.'})
        if UserModel.objects.filter(email=data.get("email")).exists():
            return Response({'code': 'reg_fail', 'message': 'Current email has already been used.'})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            social_acc = data.get('social_acc')
            if not social_acc == "Yes":
             #  send_mail('mail_subject', 'message','test.com <no-reply@test.com>', ['test@gmail.com'])

                return Response({'code': 'reg_success', 'message': 'User created successfully. Please confirm your email'}, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)            
            return Response({'code': 'reg_success', 'message': 'User created successfully.'}, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response({'code': 'reg_fail', 'message': 'Please check your data.'})
```

[Terminal snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/425Ii.png)

**serializer.py**

```
class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField(allow_null=True, max_length=None, use_url=True)
    social_acc = CharField(max_length=10)
    token = CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)
    country_code = CharField(allow_null=True, max_length=4)
    phone_number = CharField(allow_null=True, max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'image',
            'social_acc',
            'token',
            'country_code',
            'phone_number',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ('id','token')
        extra_kwargs = {"password":
                        {"write_only": True}
                        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        first_name = validated_data.get('first_name')
        last_name = validated_data.get('last_name')
        username = validated_data.get('username')
        email = validated_data.get('email')
        image = validated_data.get('image')
        password = validated_data.get('password')
        social_acc = validated_data.get('social_acc')
        country_code = validated_data['country_code']
        phone_number = validated_data['phone_number']

        user_obj = UserModel(
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            username=username,                
            email=email,
            image=image,
            country_code=country_code,
            phone_number=phone_number,
            social_acc = social_acc
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        if not social_acc == "Yes":
            user_obj.is_active = False
        user_obj.save()
        return user_obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

The problem was with android volley request. When it calls the send_mail function it takes more time than the volley default request timeout. I changed it to 20 sec and the problem is solved.